# How to change stuff in parent view, when calling popViewControllerAnimated:

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have a navigationControll with several views. Everything works properly. I now want to show an alert in the parent view, after i call the method `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in the child view. I configured the alert to show on the parent's view controller `viewDidLoad`. But what i acknowledge is that this is only called the first time the view is called. Is there any method called each time i go back to this view? thks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to remove the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;` in order for this to work:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  //YOUR CODE HERE (mine was the alert showing up)
}
```

Now the alert works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;`. Don't forget to call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` at some point in your implementation.
Another way to catch this event is to use a delegate method :

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                   animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

You can find more information visiting [UINavigationControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UINavigationControllerDelegate).

Comment: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated; didn't do anything. -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; is called everytime the view appears on the screen

Comment: the difference between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` is just the time when the method gets called either respectively before and after the view appear.

Comment: well.. for me viewDidAppear just didn't work. Or is it that i can only have one of those in each view?

Comment: both of them are `UIViewController` methods, and there is no contradiction using those two at the same time.